# Why is solr QPS so low?

Tags: solr

We are running a vanilla solr installation. [ in non-cloud mode ].

Each document has about 100 fields, and the document size is ~5k bytes.

There are multiple cores, ~20 in a single solr instance. The total number of documents combined is ~2 million.

During testing, this node gives a peak QPS of ~100. For a modern 8core, 60G machine, this seems to be really low.

Does anyone have experience with solr internals to explain, why is it so slow?

Will using lucene library directly with a thin server wrapper give a higher QPS?

Comment: Have you tried tuning the Solr configuration? http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors. Also, can you provide more information, for example, what kind of queries are you running, are you using facets etc?

Comment: Are you paging through large result-sets? As spyk noted, more details on your queries would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, the queries are complex, with faceting, filtering and sorting. The solr performance has been fairly tuned using the various online resources.

Comment: This might be a better question for the Solr User mailing list. I would provide an example of a query with your email.